# Dependency Resolution problem in Android Studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, dependencies

[I am unable to troubleshoot this problem. Does anyone have any idea about the issue. please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39x5i.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this Dependency :

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'

i think it will resolve your problem

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion helped me :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

**In project level gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

**In app level gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
```

Refer the release note for firebase android [click here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

i hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.. Thankyou a lot :) for the help

Comment: Thanks a lot Sanjay :)

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency version properly

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
```